# Context2D is undefined after it was defined

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have a simple javascript constructor-function which constructs an object that is supposed to draw conways game of life:

```js
function startGame() {
    var myGameOfLife = new GameOfLife();
    myGameOfLife.initialize(500, 500); 
}



function GameOfLife() {
    this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    this.initialize = function(width, height) {
        this.canvas.width = width;
        this.canvas.height = height;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(this.update, 20);
    }
    this.update = function(){
 this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    } 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">
<script>


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When i debug this script, i can see that in the initialize-function `this.context` gets assigned. But when the update-function is called by the interval, `this.context` is undefined.

Why is it undefined when i can clearly see it being defined before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're referring to the wrong `this` in the `update` function.

Just bind the right context (that is the context of `GameOfLife` constructor)

```
this.interval = setInterval(this.update.bind(this), 20);
```

or alternatively use an arrow function in order to let it inherit the outer scope.

```
this.update = () => {
  this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
}
```

Comment: yessss, i think i have to read more about the right use of the this-keyword

Comment: just search how the scope chain works for functions in js, that's a broad topic but very important ;)